# JFrame simple moving oval moving game positioning fails?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a game start I've made, basically a oval, and I can move it anywhere with the keyboard key arrows.

I dont want to allow it to exit the frame, so I check if X is less than 0, return if higher than width return, same for y.

But it doesn't work for < width and > height, I can go to the right and bottom until it exits the frame, why?

This is the code, (I didnt use myHeight, myWidth I manually put the sizes, the sizes are 765, 500).

```
public void movePlayer(int x, int y) {
    System.out.println(myPlayer.getX());
    if (x == 0) {
        if (y + myPlayer.getY() > 500 || y + myPlayer.getY() < 0) {
            return;
        }
        this.myPlayer.moveY(y);
    }
    else if (y == 0) {
        if (x + myPlayer.getX() > 765 || x + myPlayer.getX() < 0) {
            return;
        }           
        this.myPlayer.moveX(x);
    }
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: hmmm probably nobody knows from this code snipped nor description, for better help sooner post a  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Comment: You should consider rewriting your `if` statements. If you are simply putting a one line return if true, you would be better off just making it an `if not` statement and putting the body within that. e.g. `if (!(x + myPlayer.getX() > 765 || x + myPlayer.getX() < 0)) { ... this.myPlayer.moveX(x) ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Well, the point you are checking (your x and y) represents the upper left corner of the oval. You have to add the height when checking for the bottom, and add the width when checking for the right.

```
if (y + myPlayer.getY() + myPlayer.getHeight() > 500 || [...]) { [...]
```

And

```
if (x + myPlayer.getX() + myPlayer.getWidth() > 765 || [...]) { [...]
```

Comment: fillRect(x, y, 100, 100) so height is 100 and width is 100, i did + width and for y height, and it still goes out just by a little, when I add 50 more, it wont go out? Why ? height is 100

Comment: Your JFrame's viewport is smaller due to the window decoration. You can use `setUndecorated(true)` to test if your code works correctly. You can use the getInsets() method to check how large the borders are.